# iPhone - Disable multiple touch in whole application

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to disable "Multiple touches" through out the application, instead of setting this for every control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking Apple documentation, I think that is not possible because touch event delivery refers only on views : [Regulating Touch Event Delivery](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH3-SW20)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a simple view that you put on the top of your application who do not allows multiple touch.

Comment: I don't want to block other touches, swipes etc. The way you mentioned, i've to implement delegating the touches to other controls which is too complex with more controls.