# iPhone: disable multi touch for App

Tags: objective-c, ios, multi-touch

I want to disable multi-touch for whole app in general. Is there any property `self.disableMultiTouchForAllScreens = YES` ?
I have a lot of screens, and I dont want to disable multi touch for each of them separately.

Comment: I don't think disabling multitouch in whole application from one place is possible as multitouch is only referring to views. I am afraid that if you want to disable it. You will have to do it individually. Or may be subclass the controls and make default property of multiTouch set to False.

Comment: Why do you need to? If you don't have code that responds to multi-touch gestures then your app won't do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggestion by SimpleMan is good, why you bother about disabling just don' implement.

If you still want to do it by some reason, then might be you can do following-
you can create a subclass of uiviewcontroller, something like MyViewController : UIViewController

In the implementation of MyViewController, you can disable multi touch.
Now all other view controller of your class need to implement MyViewController instead of uiviewcontroller.

Answer (score 3):

@Jim:

I don't think it is possible as it just refers to views.

**Refer to this StackOverflow post:**

[iPhone - Disable multiple touch in whole application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190423/iphone-disable-multiple-touch-in-whole-application)

Here is answer from user **malinois** in that post"

> Looking Apple documentation, I think that is not possible because
>   touch event delivery refers only on views : [Regulating Touch Event
>   Delivery](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH3-SW20)

I am afraid that if you want to disable it. You will have to do it individually.

**One Suggestion:** (This is just a suggestion and may be easier to achieve)

I am not sure but may be you can subclass the controls you use in your app and make multitouch disabled by default in the subclass itself. Then you can use those classes as base classes of your controls and make it work.

Hope this helps you